# Python for array in array

Tags: python, arrays

I have four data sets that I am trying to call in order from a `for` statement. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
array3 = [9, 10, 11, 12]
array4 = [13, 14, 15, 16]

for [item1, item2, item3, item4] in [array1, array2, array3, array4]:
    print item1
    print item2
    print item3
    print item4
...
1
5
9
13
```

Where `item1` is an item of `array1` and `item2` is an item of `array2`, etc..

Comment: However, one usually uses *tuples* instead of *lists* (Python does not have "arrays") for this, i.e. `for item1, item2, item3, item4 in zip(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for item1, item2, item3, item4 in zip(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4):
    print item1, item2, item3, item4
```

If one of the lists is quite big, it's better to use the iterator version, [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). It reads its arguments while iterating over its return value so you avoid creating a new list with all the entries.

Comment: Don't know how my question got down voted so fast, but this worked! Thanks